# Variable in getRange on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to capture the information of the variable "row" and use it in getRange to find the data that are in the rows that were selected in the variable, for example I already defined the column I want to use, for example "A" and I want getRange to get the data from cell "A2", where the number 2 was selected in the variable "row", but I am not able to get this row value to be processed in the script, could someone help me select this?

```
function InputBox() {

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); var coluna = ui.prompt("Qual coluna você deseja copiar?", ui.ButtonSet.OK);

Logger.log(coluna.getResponseText()); Logger.log(coluna.getSelectedButton());
```

Tks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cell value using `getValue()` on Apps Script. You can add this code for getting the value in a cell which is defined by your variables `col` and `row`.

```
var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(<Sheet Name>).getRange(col+row).getValue()
```

This gets the value of the cell referring to the concatenated col and row("A"+"2").